# How to disable Google Chrome from sending data to safebrowsing-cache.google.com and safebrowsing.clients.google.com?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, privacy, safe-browsing

Unchecking **Enable phishing and malware protection** in Chrome's browser settings page does not prevent Chrome from communicating with **safebrowsing.clients.google.com** and **safebrowsing-cache.google.com** (according to packets captured using Wireshark).

How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could edit your hosts file, which will block the traffic. Maybe there is a less brute force way, but I'm sure this will work.

Add the following to your hosts file in Linux and Windows:

```
127.0.0.1 safebrowsing.clients.google.com
127.0.0.1 safebrowsing-cache.google.com
```

Add the following to your hosts file in OSX:

```
0.0.0.0 safebrowsing.clients.google.com
0.0.0.0 safebrowsing-cache.google.com
```

Your hosts file is found at the following location:

- Windows XP and later: `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- Linux: `/etc/hosts`
- OSX: `/private/etc/hosts`

More information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29

Mac OSX information added from JTM's answer to ensure everyone seeing this gets the correct information.

Comment: Fun fact: Google still uses other firm's ad-servers to pass on info about you if you block them or attempt to disable these services.

Comment: That *is* a fun fact, do you have any proof to back up the claim, out of interest? I'd like to see how they accomplish this and work on blocking them too...:)

Comment: Well, all since "goog" forensic analysis posts tend to "get disappeared" - all I can tell you is that proxy logs are your friend.

Answer (score 8):

Adding `127.0.0.1` for `safebrowsing-clients.google.com` or `safebrowsing-cache.google.com` does not help. I did just that and according my suricata logs it is still pointing to the Google's real addresses, so browser does not use `hosts` file for that. I also `tcpdump`ed the whole C-class where it previously pointed and still there is traffic to these addresses while I request totally different web sites.

However string match in iptables does the trick:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --to 41 --algo bm --string 'safebrowsing-clients' -j GOOGLE
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --to 41 --algo bm --string 'safebrowsing-cache' -j GOOGLE
iptables -I GOOGLE -m string --to 80 --algo bm --string 'google' -j DROP
```

So a bit awkward and works only in Linux, but it works.

Answer (score 5):

In response to Paul's post, the OS X file is /private/etc/hosts. Don't use 127.0.0.1 on OS X. Use 0.0.0.0. You want it to return no route, not a route to the localhost.

```
0.0.0.0 safebrowsing.clients.google.com
0.0.0.0 safebrowsing-cache.google.com
```